# Why are Repaint() and add() method not working?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

public Main(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(500,600);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0,0,500,600);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(20,30,50,50);

    repaint();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Practice");
    Main ball = new Main();
    frame.add(ball);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);

 }
}
```

In this I am getting two errors , I learned this code on youtube .

[Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQ9JEBiZSvc&list=PL3F75B774245A913F&index=1)
[Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIZiqRJzxTk&index=2&list=PL3F75B774245A913F)

i dont know why am I not able to write the errors in the question . Thats why I am writting in the comment section .

Comment: Error:(20, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method repaint()
  location: class com.company.Main

Comment: Error:(28, 14) java: no suitable method found for add(com.company.Main)
    method java.awt.Component.add(java.awt.PopupMenu) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; com.company.Main cannot be converted to java.awt.PopupMenu)
    method java.awt.Container.add(java.awt.Component) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; com.company.Main cannot be converted to java.awt.Component)

Comment: Main should extend JPanel

Comment: Paint doesn’t actually do anything because Main is not a component

Comment: Consider adding an `@Override` annotation on the methods you attempt to override, this will tell you if you are correctly overriding something.

Comment: @Jens why should I extend it . What is the use of it ?

Comment: @gtyu As a Java programmer you should know the concepts of inheritence

Comment: @MadProgrammer Main() is a constructor . But I have done same as shown in the video . Then why in my code it is showing error ?

Comment: @gtyu: If you *don't* extend `JPanel` then what are you *trying* to do?  Why do you think you have a method called `repaint()`?  Why do you think you should be able to pass an instance of your custom `Main` class to `JFrame.add()`?

Comment: @Jens but I have created the object of JPanel . So whats the use of inheritance ?

Comment: @gtyu `Main` is a class, which MUST extend from a `JComponent` based source if you wish to take advantage of the Swing paint system - that's how the API works

Comment: @gty *"but I have created the object of JPanel"* - Because the `JPanel` you've created isn't actually attached to anything which could paint it, it's pointless.  Inheritance provides you the API hook you need in order to hook into the current paint system. I think you have a lot more studying to do before you tackle something as complicated as GUIs and custom painting.

Comment: @gtyu You kind of have to think of it like a puzzle or lego.  You need to put the pieces together correctly in order to make it work - you can "try" forcing incompatible pieces together, but you just end up breaking things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, stop.  Put the video away. Grab a hot cup of coffee and go have a read of [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to gain a better understanding of how the core aspects of the paint system works in Swing.

Swing provides a number of "hooks" into which you can perform custom painting, the primary been the `paintComponent` of `JComponent`.

In order to take advantage of this, you first need a class which extends from `JComponent` or one it's children (commonly `JPanel`)

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // The background is painted for us, so we don't need to
        // You shouldn't be relying on "magic" numbers anyway
        //g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //g.fillRect(0,0,500,600);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(20,30,50,50);      
        // Never, ever, call repaint in here
        // bad things happen, fairies lose wings
        // black holes suck small children to oblivion
        // Fire Fly gets cancelled  
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 600);
    }
}
```

Now you have a custom component, you just need to it to something that can displaying

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Practice");
            TestPane ball = new TestPane();
            frame.add(ball);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```